# How to backup and restore sybase database tables using command line

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, bcp

How can I backup my sybase tables and restore using command line?
please help me with the command using bcp

I have tried using sybase central GUI
Thanks.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't specify whether you are running on Windows or Unix I'll try to cover both.

**Unix**
`bcp` is located in $SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin/
**Windows**
`bcp` is located in %SYBASE%\%SYBASE_OCS%\bin

Export

```
bcp DB_NAME..TABLE_NAME out TABLE_NAME.bcp -Sservername -Uusername -Ppassword -[c or n]
```

Choose either `-c` or `-n` depending if you want the file to be human readable or not.  I recommend using `-n` unless you have a compelling need to use `-c`  `TABLE_NAME.bcp` can be any filename, with any extension.

Import

```
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin/bcp DB_NAME..TABLE_NAME in TABLE_NAME.bcp -Sservername -Uusername -Ppassword -[c or n]
```

There are many more options and flags available, but these are the basics to get it to work.

More information abou the `bcp` utility can be found here:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570/html/utilityguide/BABGCCIC.htm

and

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570/html/utilityguide/X14951.htm