# Export table data from a particular data mart?

Tags: export, sybase, datamart

To obtain a list of all tables from all data marts in a data warehouse using Sybase, we use

```
select * from sysobjects where type = 'U'
```

However, I want to grab and export all tables from a particular data mart ("DM"). I'm relatively new to Sybase, so my gut's telling me to do something along the following lines:

```
select * from DM.sysobjects where type = 'U'
```

That's obviously not working, or else I would not be here :). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Can you specify which product/version you are using? (ASE, IQ, SQL Anywhere, etc)  Answers will vary based on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tables you mention, it looks like you are using Sybase ASE.

Sybase ASE doesn't support exporting all tables at once automatically through any method besides doing a dump of the database.  To get all the tables in a database, you will need to create a script that will loop through all the tables in a database (what you are calling data mart).

There are many different ways to go about this, and it can vary based on if you are on a *nix or windows platform, but this will at least give you an idea.

```
set nocount on
select "bcp "+ name + " out " + name + ".bcp -Uusername -Sservername -Ppassword -c
from sysobjects where type = 'U'
go
```

This will give you a script file that should be easy to run against the server.  `-c` denotes that it's a *character mode* or plain text file.  There are other options for changing delimiters, and more but this should get you started.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931683/how-to-backup-and-restore-sybase-database-tables-using-command-line/16940661#16940661) has more details on using `bcp`