# linux connect to remote sybase and backup/dump

Tags: linux, sybase, remote-access

I am on a CentOS machine and connected to a remote Sybase service through freetds/isql.

I have no problem connecting to the remote database through isql.

I'd like to dump the database to my localhost (my CentOS machine).  From the isql prompt, I cannot do this with the 'backup database' command; I think it tries to back up to the remote machine instead of the local machine.

How can I backup to my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase backup and restore does not support remote operation.  It will only dump/load from local partitions.

If you need to get the database to your local system you can either dump the database then sftp the file to your local system, or use the `bcp` utility (which supports remote operations) to extract data from the remote system and import it into your local system.

[More on using bcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931683/how-to-backup-and-restore-sybase-database-tables-using-command-line/16940661#16940661)